# I cannot import pyWavelets

Tags: python, eclipse

I want to use PyWavelets with my Mac OS-X but I cannot import pyWavelets.
Please tell me how to solve this problem.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jun/Documents/workspace/Iris/IrisIRis.py", line 4, in <module>
  import pywt
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/pywt/__init__.py", line 15, in<module>
  PILLOW_VERSION = '3.0.0'  # Pillow
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/pywt/_pywt.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/pywt/_pywt.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
  File "__init__.pxd", line 155, in init _pywt(/private/var/folders/7b/8tpk8d0x1mdf9tdj87mqwj6r0000gn/T/easy_install-U3Ba9H/PyWavelets-0.3.0/pywt/src/_pywt.c:38072)
  ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

Comment: 'numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling"  - I'd look into incompatible versions of NumPy.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it.